# Как составить RegEx для строк?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

```
1.0 m = 60.00 s
2 day = 48 hour

5 year = ? day
```

где: 1) буква или строка до 15 символов; 2) положительное натуральное или вещественное число. 3) вместо 2-й цифры может быть символ '?'.

RegEx не владею сейчас, может, кто-то сможет помочь?

Comment: Овладейвате. Вот хорошие видео. [Регулярки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UCQNnxBEWY&t)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, верно ли я понял. Но вот регулярное выражение для данных строк:

```
^(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\s(m|day|year)\s=\s(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\?)\s(s|hour|day)$
```

Обязательно с Multiline флагом в опциях.

Проверить правильность и протестировать можно на этом сайте [systemtextregularexpressions.com](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=XihcZCsoPzpcLlxkezEsMn0pPylccyhtfGRheXx5ZWFyKVxzPVxzKFxkKyg%2fOlwuXGR7MSwyfSk%2ffFw%2fKVxzKHN8aG91cnxkYXkpJA%3d%3d&t=MS4wIG0gPSA2MC4wMCBzDQoyIGRheSA9IDQ4IGhvdXINCjUgeWVhciA9ID8gZGF5&op=2)

Вот группы:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]